# Click on submit button, should disable the checkbox button Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="alert.acknowledged" ng-disabled="alert.acknowledged" ng-click="onacknowledgedClick(alert)">
</td>
<td>
<span ng-if="!alert.acknowledgeInProgress">{{alert.acknowledgedComments}}</span>
<div ng-if="alert.acknowledgeInProgress">
<input type="text" style="height:30px; width:150px" ng-model="alert.acknowledgedComments"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="saveAlert(alert)"> Submit </button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="cancelAlert(alert)" data-dismiss="modal"> Cancel </button>
```

When I click on checkbox button, the text textfield with submit button will be popped up. After entering the comments on textfield, when the user clicks on submit button, the checkbox should get disabled. Can anyone give me some inputs on this? 
How to disable the checkbox button, once when I click on Submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest jQuery:

```js
$("#submit").click(function(){
  $("#alertAcknowledged").attr("disabled", true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="alert.acknowledged" ng-disabled="alert.acknowledged" id="alertAcknowledged" ng-click="onacknowledgedClick(alert)"></td>
                        <td>
                            <span ng-if="!alert.acknowledgeInProgress">{{alert.acknowledgedComments}}</span>
                            <div ng-if="alert.acknowledgeInProgress">
                                <input type="text" style="height:30px; width:150px" ng-model="alert.acknowledgedComments"/>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="saveAlert(alert)" id="submit"> Submit </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="cancelAlert(alert)" data-dismiss="modal"> Cancel </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JavaScript to do this. Make an event listener for the submit button that disables the checkbox and the cancel button that does `display: none;` to the text input. For info about event listeners visit this site: [Event Listeners](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)
This is what you should do:

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {document.getElementById("alertAcknowledged").disabled = true;})
document.getElementById("cancel").addEventListener("click", function() {document.getElementById("text").style.display = "none";})
```

```html
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="alert.acknowledged" ng-disabled="alert.acknowledged" id="alertAcknowledged" ng-click="onacknowledgedClick(alert)"></td>
                        <td>
                            <span ng-if="!alert.acknowledgeInProgress">{{alert.acknowledgedComments}}</span>
                            <div ng-if="alert.acknowledgeInProgress">
                                <input type="text" id="text" style="height:30px; width:150px" ng-model="alert.acknowledgedComments"/>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="saveAlert(alert)" id="submit"> Submit </button>
                                <button type="button" id="cancel" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="cancelAlert(alert)" data-dismiss="modal"> Cancel </button>
```

Comment: I am working on Angular JS. Can you help me with Angular js?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know angular. Should I delete the answer?

Comment: No. Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes! Can you give me a function when I click on cancel button, the text field shouldn't come. It should be hidden.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much.

Comment: The addition is complete.

Answer (score 0):

add disableCheckbox as a paramet and set it inside the click function.

**HTML**

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="alert.acknowledged" ng-disabled="alert.disableCheckbox" ng-click="onacknowledgedClick(alert)">
</td>
<td>
<span ng-if="!alert.acknowledgeInProgress">{{alert.acknowledgedComments}}</span>
<div ng-if="alert.acknowledgeInProgress">
<input type="text" style="height:30px; width:150px" ng-model="alert.acknowledgedComments"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="saveAlert(alert)"> Submit </button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="cancelAlert(alert)" data-dismiss="modal"> Cancel </button>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.onacknowledgedClick = function(alert){ 
  alert.acknowledgeInProgress = true;   
} 

$scope.saveAlert = function(alert) { 
  /*$scope.alert.acknowledged = true;*/
  alert.disableCheckbox = true; 
  alert.acknowledgeInProgress = true; 
  var alertUrl =  $incidentsUrl+"/"+alert.alertForIncident.incidentID+"/alerts/"+alert.alertID; 

  $http.put(alertUrl, alert).then(function(result) { 
    alert.acknowledgeInProgress = false; 
  });
}
```

Comment: This is my saveAlert controller:                                                                                               $scope.saveAlert = function(alert) {
   $scope.alert.acknowledged = true;
   alert.acknowledgeInProgress = true;
   var alertUrl = $incidentsUrl+ "/" +alert.alertForIncident.incidentID+"/alerts/"+alert.alertID;
   $http.put(alertUrl, alert).then(function(result) {
    alert.acknowledgeInProgress = false;
            });
   
            
  }   It's still the same before clicking on submit button only, the checkbox is getting disabled.

Comment: post your entire controller (if it's not too huge), but also see Christian's answer. he makes a good point.

Comment: $scope.onacknowledgedClick = function(alert){
   alert.acknowledgeInProgress = true; 
  }
  
  $scope.saveAlert = function(alert) {
   /*$scope.alert.acknowledged = true;*/
   alert.acknowledgeInProgress = true;
   var alertUrl = $incidentsUrl+ "/" +alert.alertForIncident.incidentID+"/alerts/"+alert.alertID;
   $http.put(alertUrl, alert).then(function(result) {
    alert.acknowledgeInProgress = false;
            });
   
            
  }

Comment: Couldn't you just have a disableCheckbox parameter on alert that is set to true in the click function?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using jquery as much as possible in angular. Here's a good read http://tech.zumba.com/2014/08/02/angularjs-forget-jquery/

So, it looks like your ng-disabled="alert.acknowledged" but ng-click="alert.acknowledged" as well. This means when you click the radio button, alert.acknowledged is set to true, so it gets disabled.

You probably want a different value in ng-disabled, maybe ng-disabled="disableRadioBtn", then in your submit controller you can set $scope.disableRadioBtn = false;